# Exceptions in threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

If an exception in a thread is thrown, is the main thread affected if that exception isn't caught in that thread?

Why? As far as I can remember, exceptions are stack based and so when one occurs the stack unwinds right? But if a thread has its own stack, why should the main thread be affected?

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    std::thread([]{
        throw std::runtime_error("HELLO");
    }).detach();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
}
```

This thread is detached. I can't understand why the main program would crash. For me it's like a child process crashing and causing the parent to crash..

:S Can someone explain how exceptions in threads work?

Comment: But it cannot be caught in the main thread. Only in the child thread itself. So why should it affect the main thread then?

Comment: Could it be that the thread throws exception befors detach will be executed?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow No sir. I made it sleep for 5 seconds before throwing. Giving it enough time to detach. I made the main thread sleep for 10 seconds. It indeed crashes no matter what. I'll probably accept Dai's answer if there are no others by the time the accept button timer cools down. It makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to MSDN ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac9f67ah.aspx ), if no appropriate `catch` handler is found, then the `terminate` function will be called. `terminate` by default calls the C runtime function `abort` though you can override this if necessary by calling `set_terminate`.

In a multi-threaded scenario `terminate` would be called in this secondary thread, which would cause your program to quit - i.e. your main/parent/entry thread would stop immediately and your process killed by the OS.

It is not fair to compare threads to processes - processes are memory-isolated from each other, whereas threads are not. An exception could be raised if the program is in an unexpected or undesirable state, which means data in the program's memory space could be corrupted, it is important the program handles the exception appropriately and if not, terminates (to avoid the risk of writing corrupted data to disk, which is a very bad thing(TM). I think this explains the motivation behind having the program `abort` if any thread doesn't handle an exception, because if the main thread continued execution it could be operating on corrupt or invalid data, which you don't want.

This is the same as-in other [platforms like C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228965(v=vs.110).aspx) (except instead of `terminate`, it's `AppDomain.UnhandledException`, and is recoverable), though Java is a notable exception (no pun intended) where the thread will terminate but the process will continue running - I suppose (warning: speculation!) in Java's case because memory itself wouldn't be corrupted there's not as much harm in allowing the process to continue, even if application object state might be corrupted.